# Winsock2 connection from an external IP address

Tags: c, ip, winsock, winsock2

I wrote a simple char program with winsock2 in C using the examples in the msdn.It works unless I'm trying to connect to the server via a computer which isn't connected to the same router, (using the external address of the network)

I can a sure that it is not a firewall issue on the computer or the router, I've no problem setting up a minecraft server and connect to it externally.

I've tried to bind the external ip address to the server but it turns out it is impossible.

Is there somesort of flag that allows connection from an external IP?

Comment: When binding the local server socket, are you using `INADDR_ANY`? What problems do you get when trying to bind to the external address?

Comment: Yes I'm using INADDR_ANY to bind the socket, it works with no problem.but I can't bind it with my external IP, I get error 10049.

Comment: That you can not connect from the outside is most likely a firewall issue. You have to check the firewall rules and logs.

Comment: It seems very unlikely,I've tried to turn on my antivirus, firewall and I set my router to be a DMZ to my internal IP. Moreover I have no problem set up a game server and connecting to it (via external computer)

Comment: Did you check what error 10049 indicates? If not, you might like to do so here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've check it, I've mentioned that it is impossible to bind an external ip.

Answer (score 0):

A server socket can only bind to the IP(s) that belong to the machine it is running on.  Binding to `INADDR_ANY` handles that for you.

In order for a client outside the network to connect to that server, the client must connect to an open IP/Port on the router itself, not the server machine.  The router must be configured to forward inbound connections on its public IP/Port to the server's IP/Port.

For example, say you have a server socket listening on port 12345 of a machine that has a local LAN IP of 192.168.0.1, and the router has a public IP of 206.152.65.1.  You would bind the socket to 192.168.0.1:12345, then open port 12345 (or any available port you want) on the router and define a Port Forwarding rule to map that port to 192.168.0.1:12345.  Now, the outside client can connect to 206.152.65.1:12345 and the server on 192.168.0.1:12345 will see the connection.

More generally, any network packet that is directed to 206.152.65.1:12345 will be adjusted and forwarded to 192.168.0.1:12345.  The router takes care of adjusting the packet headers so parties think they are communicating with each other and not know a router is in the middle.